# aspnet core error: Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RequireHttpsAttribute'

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, iis-8

I am building and testing a aspnet core app using SSL. Running the site in IIS Express works fine. So, I thought I might see what's required to get it running on IIS 10. As expected, there are a few issues.

First off, I need to clarify that I have successfully hosted a non SSL aspnet app in IIS, so all the bits needed for an aspnet core app are there. But in the case of a SSL app, all I get is a message in the browser saying that an error occurred. Also nothing useful in the webserver logs.

So, my first test was to try and run the app directly in the published folder using dotnet xxx.dll. That's when I noticed the authorization error.

```
 services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
  {
    options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
  });
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: that would be expected if you don't have an ssl certificate setup for the site in IIS.

Comment: I have a self signed certificate set up that is used by the application pool - No Managed Code. In any case, the error does not even involve IIS at this point. The error is being thrown by the core application using the Kestrel webserver.

Comment: I have now decorated the Home Controller with the [Allow Anonymous] attribute but the same error is being thrown.

Comment: the error as you can see is happening when it tries to redirect to ssl on localhost without port. I am doubtful that your local ssl cert is bound to localhost ie default web site in IIS. ssl is not attached to application pool it is in the bindings for the site in IIS. I would test it in IIS with a ssl and a static html file first to make sure

Comment: As I mentioned previously, the screenshot above is the error I get when I run the  dotnet xxx.dll command ( inside the deployment folder ). My understanding is that the error is being thrown by the Kestrel web server. IIS is not even running at this point. Perhaps Kestrel needs to be notified of the cert. I think is the cause of the error. What I need to find out is how the notify Kestrel of the cert. If that issue is fixed, I can go to the next stage and engage IIS as a reverse proxy server.

Comment: I have added a screenshot showing the ssl binding.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by generating a pfx certificate as explained on Shawn Wildermuth's blog (https://wildermuth.com/2016/10/26/Testing-SSL-in-ASP-NET-Core). Once this is done, modify your Program.cs file as follows:

[image]

Once this is done,re publish your project (command: dotnet publish)and move the pfx file into the published folder.

Now, when you run dotnet MyFileName.dll in the published folder, it can access the cert and everything works. ( Well it did for me )